# building class library (universal windows) lead to build error

Tags: xaml, uwp, build-error

I wanted to make an **universal windows project** which I can use in all projects which I might create in the future. So my idea was simple I startet to implement all my **pages**, **entities** and so on in a **class library (universal windows)**.

After a short amount of time, when i want to build I get an "**Object reference is not set to an instance of an object**" - error in my project ***while building my project***. The strange thing about this is that I get as project my project name but no file seems to be affected.

It starts with a simple error message which say my page **does not implement** a definition for `InitializeComponent()` and when I want to **build the project** then I get the **error message**. Even rebuild or clean and build does not solve the problem.

I don't know how to fix this and I'm lost... I already deleted couple of projects then after a time the error accures again. **I already got a new VM with the latest VS Professional** but still no solution...

I've uploaded a SampleSandBoxProject where you can see, what I mean.

Here is a Step-by-Step guide:

- Create a style file
- Create a class which represents an object for the user control ↓
- Create a user control what defines a gridview for the object ↑

→ Set some properties in code behind

→ Reference the style file in xaml

- Create a page which uses the user control

=> the object is no longer buildable

Here I've prepared a SampleProject which contains only the step I did take before it was no longer buildable...

[SampleSandBoxProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qawzserkunzbwj/SandBoxProject.zip?dl=0)

Hopefully you guys can help me I have really no clue what to do...

Thanks in Advance:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SampleUserControl.xaml`, you cannot bind to the `Click` event like that: `Click="{Binding ClickEvent}"`. When you remove this bit, the project compiles.

You probably meant `Command="{Binding ClickEvent}"`, where `ClickEvent` is a property in the ViewModel implementing the `ICommand` interface.

Comment: You Sir solved my problem! Thank you very much. But I think the error message does not specify what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I agree, the error message is too generic, as it often is in XAML.